# POM err when developing plug-in for Atlassian Confluence

Tags: eclipse, java-8, maven-3, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I'm writing plug-in for Atlassian Confluence platform. My environment:

- Atlassian SDK
- Maven 3.2.1
- JDK v8
- Eclipse IDE

When it comes to POM, along the following line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I've got the following error:

```
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-confluence-plugin:6.2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-confluence-plugin:jar:6.2.2
```

The POM itself:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-confluence-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${amps.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <productVersion>${confluence.version}</productVersion>
                <productDataVersion>${confluence.data.version}</productDataVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Anyone come accross this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just switched to **IntelliJ** and all the Maven's problems vanished.